# Questions regarding the proof for the set of real numbers that have a decimal expansion with the digit $5$ appearing infinitely often is a Borel set.

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, borel-sets

I have found two distinct proofs for the problem:

Show that the set of real numbers that have a decimal expansion with the digit 5 appearing infinitely often is a Borel set.

Both of which I could not prove some steps.

Proof 1) Let $E:= \{ x \in \mathbb{R}: \text{$x$ has a decimal expansion with the digit 5 appearing infinitely often} \}$, and let $E_n := \{ x \in \mathbb{R} : \text{$x$ has a decimal expansion with the digit 5 appearing in the $n$th position}\}$.
We show that $\displaystyle E = \limsup_{n \to \infty} E_n = \bigcap_{n \geq 1} \bigcup_{m \geq n} E_m$, so that $E$ is a Borel set as long as $E_n$ is a Borel set.

I could not prove why $\displaystyle E = \limsup_{n \to \infty} E_n = \bigcap_{n \geq 1} \bigcup_{m \geq n} E_m$, and cannot proceed with the proof.

---

Proof 2) Let $E_n := \{ x \in \mathbb{R} : \text{$x$ has a deciaml expansion with the digit $5$ appearing only $n$ times}\}$.
Then $E = \mathbb{R} \backslash (\bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty} E_n)$, hence $E$ is a Borel set as long as $E_n$ is a Borel set.
(This $E$ is the same as in proof 1)

I could not prove why $E_n$ is a Borel set, or why $E_n$ is closed.

---

Any corrections regarding the proofs will be appreciated!

Comment: for (1) if $x$ has finitely many $5$s, then there is some $k$ such that $x$ doesn't have any $5$s at or after position $k$. That is, it is not in $E_m$ for any $m \ge k$, and therefore not in $\bigcup_{m\ge k}E_m$, and so not in the limsup. Conversely, if $x$ has infinitely many $5$s, for every $k$ there is always some $m \ge k$ with $x \in E_m$. Thus it is always in $\bigcup_{m\ge k}E_m$, and thus is in the limsup.